# Can't display div element inside another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="wrap_menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#modelos" class="link">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#empresa" class="link">Empresa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#galeria" class="link">Galeria</a></li>
        <li class="big"><a href="#representantes" class="link">Representantes</a></li>
        <li><a href="cadastro" class="link">Cadastro</a></li>
        <li><a href="contato" class="link">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="conteudo">

    <div id="modelos">
        <ul id="fotos_modelo">
            <li><img src="modelos/modelo_1.png"/></li>
            <li><img src="modelos/modelo_2.png"/></li>
            <li><img src="modelos/modelo_3.png"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="empresa">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p><br/>
        <h4>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</h4>
    </div>

</div>
```

And this JavaScript that make content visible/hidden:

```
$('.menu a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hideContentDivs();
    var tmp_div = jQuery(this).parent().index();
    jQuery('.menu li').eq(tmp_div).addClass("selected");
    jQuery('#conteudo div').eq(tmp_div).fadeIn(1000);
});         

function hideContentDivs(){
    jQuery('#conteudo div').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).fadeOut();
        jQuery('.menu li').removeClass("selected");
    });
}
hideContentDivs();
```

My problem: If i put another `DIV` element inside of my content, example:

```
<div id="modelos">
    <div id="this_div">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

my `this_div` is not displayed...

see: http://jsfiddle.net/hQ7y5/130/

Comment: side question-----why do you switch between using $ and jQuery ?? Why not just use $ all the time?

Comment: i don't know why, but if i use $ where i'm using jQuery, i got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function `.. i'm using jquery.innerfade, maybe this is in conflict... i'm realy don't know why....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `.main div` to `.main>div`. Then it will hide only the immediate child div

```
function hideContentDivs() {
    $('.main>div').each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hQ7y5/131/

Comment: `$('.main>div').hide();` will do the same thing without writing loop.

Answer (score 1):

First correction in your jsfiddle is, **you have used 'link3' id twice, please correct that**.
And secondly use :

```
function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.main>div').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
```

working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hQ7y5/132/

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideContentDivs(){
    jQuery('#conteudo div').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).fadeOut();
        jQuery('.menu li').removeClass("selected");
    });
}
hideContentDivs();
```

This will hide all the div's within `#conteudo` (any depth). If you want an immediate child use `#conteudo > div`